# Materialized view "shape of prebuilt table does not match definition query"

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

A date column is causing "shape of prebuilt table does not match definition query" error.

I deleted the column and readded it with the ddl below. I still see the same error.

`ALTER TABLE schema.table DROP COLUMN column_name;`

`ALTER TABLE schema.table ADD column_name DATE;`

```
CREATE 
    MATERIALIZED VIEW schema.table ON PREBUILT TABLE WITH REDUCED PRECISION
        USING INDEX REFRESH ON DEMAND COMPLETE
        USING DEFAULT LOCAL ROLLBACK SEGMENT DISABLE QUERY REWRITE AS SELECT
... column names ...
from schema.table1;
```

What about the date column is causing this issue ? Funny thing is this isn't even  a new column. This column was already existing with 48 others. I was trying add a 50th column to the MView when this column started acting up.

What is even more puzzling is this same `create materialized view` works fine in another environment. The table definitions across environments are exactly same character to character. I know because I did a diff between both of them.

The way I was able to diagnose that this column was the culprit is by dropping one column at a time and trying to create the materialized view. I found it after 35 columns. This is miserable. Is there a better of doing this ?

Comment: Yes, I manually walked through matching each column in the table and the materialized view query. I left the references to schema and table by mistake. Can I request you to change them in your comment to schema and table ?

Comment: which version of oracle are you using? and can you also share your select query?

Comment: Deleted my previous comment containing original names. For posterity, was: You don't show the step where you create schema.table. Can you confirm that the columns there (e.g. DESCRIBE schema.table) match the column list in your CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW statement?

Comment: That syntax looks wrong now. The table name after `CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW` shouldn't be the same as the table name at the end of your `SELECT`. You prebuilt the table, right? So you have a table where you want the materialized view to be stored plus a separate  source table?

Comment: Thankyou for removing the original names.

I've changed the name of the source table to table1. 

Both the table (not referring to the source table) and the materialized view are already existing. The materialized view is a scheduled on. I changed it to PREBUILT one while trying a few things. I have to change it back to a scheduled one eventually.

If I populate the column names in the query above the materialized view is created without an any errors.

Comment: @Simonare Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.4.0 - 64bit Production

The select query is shown above. I've only removed the column names, switched schema and table names.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the bit about switching it back to being scheduled. The view can still be refreshed automatically if the table is prebuilt. Just to clarify your previous comment, you compared the columns in the table schema.table (same name as the materialized view) to the column list (not the columns in the table schema.table1)?

Comment: Yes I compared the column names of the target table with the column of the source table and I also compared the columns of target table with the names in the select query of the materialized view.

Comment: What about comparing column types?

Answer (score 1):

Just had a problem like this, maybe not your case, but good for try/know, its related with sqldeveloper, doesn't know if its your case.

A friend and I were trying to recreate a table and materialized view, my friend copied the DDL and simple removed one column, but when executing he got that "shape of prebuilt table does not match definition query" error.

He passed me the same code and on my machine it worked.

The thing is that some of the properties of the sqldeveloper (screenshot provided) were different in our settings.

We highly suspect on (we have to confirm) **Length** and **Date Format** (in spanish in the screenshot), also matched the decimal and group settings, just marked what we had different, so when he changed settings to match mine, the script worked.

The thing is that you define the type of data for the table, but the materialized view seems to get these from the settings and that affects the "shape" of the view.

[image: Spanish sqldeveloper settings]

Answer (score 0):

Cast the value you are selecting into the data type of the prebuilt table column, even if the select datatype size is same or smaller than the table column size

```
create table person_mvw
(
person_number varchar2(20)
person_name varchar2(50)
person_address varchar2(50)
);

-- This may not work
create materialized view person_mvw
on prebuilt table as
select
customer_nbr
, customer_firstname || ' ' || customer_lastname
customer_address
from customer 
;

-- Try this even if the datatype size is same or smaller than the table column size, even if you have used substr function to reduce the size.
create materialized view person_mvw
on prebuilt table as
select
cast(customer_nbr as varchar2(20))
, cast ((customer_firstname || ' ' || customer_lastname) as varchar2(50))
, cast (customer_address as varchar2(50))
from customer 
;
```